# Prove that either $r \geq 1$ or $r = \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, power-series

> > Let $\{a_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|^2 < \infty.$ Consider the power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ with radius of convergence $r.$ Show that either $r \geq 1$ or $r = \infty.$

How do I prove that? Any suggestion or hint regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$
converges absolutely when $|z|<1$. I suggest using Cauchy-Schwarz. By hypothesis,
the $\ell^2$-norm of the sequence $(a_n)$ is finite.

Comment: What I can see @Lord Shark the Unknown is that for any $z \in \Bbb C$ with $|z|<1$ and for all $n \geq 0$ we have $$\left ( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \left |a_k z^k \right | \right )^2 \leq \frac {1} {1 - |z|^2} \left ( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} |a_k|^2 \right ).$$ Does it guarantee that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left |a_n z^n \right |$ is convergent for $|z| < 1$ or in other words $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ is absolutely convergent for $|z| < 1$ ?

Comment: Can I conclude from here that for all $z \in \Bbb C$ with $|z| < 1$ and for all $n \geq 0$ $$\left ( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left |a_n z^n \right | \right )^2 \leq \frac {1} {1 - |z|^2} \left ( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|^2 \right )?$$

Comment: I think that I have to use limit superior and limit inferior argument here. Right?

Comment: Done it thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For any bounded sequence $(a_n)$ the power series $\sum a_n x^{n}$ converges for $|x| < 1$ (by comparison with a geometric series). Hence the radius of convergence is  a real number $\geq 1$ or $+\infty$. Note that $\sum |a_n|^{2} <\infty$ implies that $a_n \to 0$ and hence $(a_n)$ is bounded.